# Google Maps embed code doesn't always display the directions icon

Tags: html, wordpress, google-maps

I'm getting differing results when I embed Google Maps code on wordpress post using a custom html block.

Sometimes it displays the directions icon (which I want) and sometimes it doesn't.

With the following 2 embed codes, the first one had an address, the second one had a pin (both options are necessary). However the address brings up the directions icon and the long/lat pin does not.

Do I need to tweak the code somehow to make sure the directions icon always shows?

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3369.4406686507573!2d116.24852251744383!3d-32.380547099999994!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x2a32574e673b65f7%3A0x54859ed2b0cfb12a!2sSullivan%20Rock%20car%20park!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1635496597923!5m2!1sen!2sau" 
style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>


<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3385.1021641700722!2d116.16264181418593!3d-31.95812498122696!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMzHCsDU3JzI5LjMiUyAxMTbCsDA5JzUzLjQiRQ!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1635498170953!5m2!1sen!2sau" 
style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you have Google Maps Embed API ? I think since 2014  long/lat pin  requires api

Comment: Yes I do. I've just double checked and it's enabled. I've also regenerated the API key because it was over 12 months old. But I may have the API restriction settings set up incorrectly. Have turned on HTTP referers and selected Restrict Key to Maps Embed API.